# Struggle to understand the logic behind the booleans inside the while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, boolean-logic

I want to ask a question about a boolean question inside the loop.

Let me first explain this:
if I Input help, then it will show me

start - to start the car,

stop - to stop the car,

quit- to exit,

If I Input start, stop, quit it will print above individually.

If I Input start and stop again it will show ("the car is already started") or ("the car is already stopped").

please see the code below:

```
command = ""

started = False

while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started: 
            print("the car is already started")
        else:
            started = True 
            print("start the car")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started: 
            print("the car is already stopped")
        else:
            started = False 
            print("stop the car")
    elif command == "help":
        print("""
start - to start the car
stop - to stop the car
quit- to exit
                """)
    elif command == "exit":
        print("exit the game")
        break
else:
    print("don't understand")
```

My question is how do python find out if I already typed start or stop, which will print ("the car is already started") or ("the car is already stopped").
The boolean **started** which is defined as False at the beginning seems to be the answer in this loop, but I don't understand the logic behind this.

Thank you so much all for your help and support, really appreciate it.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger, so you can see what happens to this variable over the course of the program's execution.

Comment: `if started` meaning if the variable started is True (or Truthy) execute the following.

Comment: `started` keeps track of the status (of the car). `if started` is shorthand for `if started == True` or `if started is True`, same for the negation. You can not start a started car, hence you somehow need to keep track of the status.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now.